# How to pull current year and prior year data from the same table in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake where i am trying to pull for instance an entry date and the total amount of that day and also get the same entry date but for prior year and the total amount for that prior year.

I only get nulls for the prior year date and amount.

SQL:
select *

```
  from ((
    select  
     TO_DATE(a.RpEntTrDt, 'MM/DD/YY') RpEntTrDt,
     sum(a.RpEntTrAmt) Report_Entry_Transaction_Amount_PY
    from "EC_ERP_PROD"."PUBLIC"."CONCUR" a
    Where a.RpEntTrDt <> '' 
   -- and TO_DATE(a.RpEntTrDt, 'MM/DD/YY') = '2018-05-01'
     group by TO_DATE(a.RpEntTrDt, 'MM/DD/YY')) aa
     
     left outer join
    (select  
     --DATEADD(year, -1, TO_DATE(trim(a.RpEntTrDt), 'MM/DD/YY')) RpEntTrDtPY,
     TO_DATE(a.RpEntTrDt, 'MM/DD/YY') RpEntTrDtPY,
     sum(a.RpEntTrAmt) Report_Entry_Transaction_Amount_PY
    from "EC_ERP_PROD"."PUBLIC"."CONCUR" a
    Where a.RpEntTrDt <> '' 
     and TO_DATE(a.RpEntTrDt, 'MM/DD/YY') =  current_date () -1
     group by TO_DATE(a.RpEntTrDt, 'MM/DD/YY')
    ) bb
on aa.RpEntTrDt = bb.RpEntTrDtPY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query..Doing the self join on the same aggrgated table data.

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
  (SELECT to_date(a.rpenttrdt, 'MM/DD/YY') rpenttrdt,
          sum(a.rpenttramt) report_entry_transaction_amount
   FROM "EC_ERP_PROD"."PUBLIC"."CONCUR" a
   WHERE a.rpenttrdt <> ''
   GROUP BY a.rpenttrdt) aa
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT to_date(b.rpenttrdt, 'MM/DD/YY') rpenttrdtpy,
          sum(b.rpenttramt) report_entry_transaction_amount_py
   FROM "EC_ERP_PROD"."PUBLIC"."CONCUR" b
   WHERE b.rpenttrdt <> ''
   GROUP BY b.rpenttrdt) bb ON to_date(a.rpenttrdt, 'MM/DD/YY') = dateadd(YEAR, -1, to_date(bb.rpenttrdt, 'MM/DD/YY'))
) c
```